# How do you change the size of JQGrid's Edit Dialog Box?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, pager

In a JQGrid grid, when you select a row and press the edit button, a dialog box pops up to allow you to enter information in the fields of that row.  How do you specify a default height, width, and location of the dialog box that pops up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [docs for Form Editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing), you can use the following options:

- top - the initial top position of modal dialog. The default value of 0 mean the top position from the upper left corner of the grid. When jqModal option is true (see below) and jqModal plugin is present any value different from 0 mean the top position from upper left corner of the window.
- left - the initial left position of modal dialog. The default value of 0 mean the left position from the upper left corner of the grid. When jqModal option is true (see below) and jqModal plugin is present any value different from 0 mean the left position from upper left corner of the window.
- width - the width of confirmation dialog
- height - the entry height of confirmation dialog

Comment: I guess the real problem is that I am creating my CRUD buttons through the pager, and I don't specifically call the editGridRow() function, any way to specify attributes in the #pager constructor.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.
[JqGrid How to change width of edit form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901306/jqgrid-how-to-change-width-of-edit-form)