# JqGrid How to change width of edit form?

Tags: jqgrid

I don't understand how to change width of edit form in JqGrid. I found option 'width' but I don't know how to use it (there isn't example).

Answer (score 26):

You probably know the method [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#how_to_use). It has parameters in the form

```
$("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{parameters},
                  prmEdit, prmAdd, prmDel, prmSearch, prmView);
```

where the  parameter `prmEdit` can contain any options of [editGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#editgridrow) method inclusive the [width](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#editgridrow) option which you need. So if you need for example to have edit form with 500px width instead of default 300px you can use

```
$("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{},{width:500});
```

To simplify you the implementation I modified an example from my another answer so that the edit dialog has 200px: see it live [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomFormEdit1.htm).

Comment: @peter: You welcome! Because you are relatively new at the stackoverflow.com consider to use voting up the answers or questions (see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) and accepting one from the answers (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) or both (voting up and accepting). This will the standard way to say "tanks" and it helps another people quickly to find the most helpful answer.

Comment: @jessica: You welcome! I find also many places of the documentation writen in the wrong way. One describes parameters of the function `editGridRow` and 99% of the users should use the settings just as `prmEdit` and `prmAdd` parameters of `navGrid`. It is difficult to understand. jqGrid has wiki documentation and everybody, also you, can change the documentation. I also wanted to do this, but didn't found the time for this till now.

Comment: also `width:'500px'` will not work, you have to put `width:500`

Comment: @ChtiwiMalek: Sorry, but I don't understand your comment. Where in the code you could see `width:'500px'` in my code? `width` should be integer. If one use non-numeric value then jqGrid use `width: "auto"` instead.

Comment: @Oleg: your code is correct. just saying that the value should be numeric not a string.

Answer (score 3):

you can change in edit settings by using the following code.

```
editSettings = {
recreateForm:true,
jqModal:false,
reloadAfterSubmit:false,
closeOnEscape:true,
savekey: [true,13],
closeAfterEdit:true,
zIndex:1000,
**width: 450**,
pgbuttons:false,

.jqGrid('navGrid','#Pager',editSettings,...)
```

Comment: `<br>` should not be in JSON